# change selected attributes for current_user using devise & rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a User model that has a number of additional attributes (like settings and some log info) that are only required in certain situations and contain a fair amount of data.

If I was selecting a user from the database myself then I'd use something like this in the majority of cases (where I didn't need those extra attrs);

```
standard_attrs = [:id, :username]
User.select(standard_attrs).find(params[:user_id])
```

(That's just an example case, `standard_attrs` would contain more than those attrs, but not the full set of user attrs.)

With devise it selects * from users when it loads the current_user object.  Is there a way to change what devise selects when it loads current_user? Or would the better solution be to move the less frequently required attrs onto a separate model?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would move additional data to separate model, you can use draper gem because it is obviously Decorator pattern.

At the following link:
http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/

Look at the step 7:

"For cases where callback logic only needs to run in some circumstances or including it in the model would give the model too many responsibilities, a Decorator is useful."

So you have some logic ( get additional data for certain user ). Since this data is in database, this model should persist in database as well.

IMHO Decorator is way to go. You actually don't need draper for this, you can do this with PORO(plain old ruby object).

Bottom line, create another model with user id, create function in user for running query to get this data :

```
def additional_attributes
    AdditionaAttributes.find(self.id)
end
```

And use it like that. Since you have some logic to decide when to call it, you won't have any problems.

NOTE: I used term decorator because it is closest description. Implement this like PORO extended from ActiveModel and you are good to go.

Comment: thanks @NickCatib. I think I will take the PORO route as that suits what I need best (what I need is simple, so that's perfect!)